# Android custom view background selection

Tags: android, background, selection, custom-view

I have a custom view:

```
public class MyView extends RelativeLayout {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_view, this);
    }
}
```

with an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

I also have a selector for the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/top_press" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/top_idle" /> <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

When I use the selector as a background it doesn't work:

```
<com.example.MyView style="@style/someStyle" 
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector_top" android:clickable="true"/>
```

However, when I put the background from the internal xml it does work:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:background="@drawable/item_selector_top"/>
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: The same problem here. Everything seems to be OK, but it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass parent's state to your custom view's children. Use:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Note: if your custom view has advanced hierarchy like A->B->C and you want 'C' view to handle state behavior you should put duplicateParentState to 'A' and 'B' views too.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Adding this attribute does not change anything.